# A workflow in SharePoint 2007 that start every last day 2359Hrs for each month

Tags: workflow, list, document-library

Is it possible to have a workflow in SharePoint 2007 that run on the last day at 2359 Hrs every month to modify some values in a SharePoint List or SharePoint Document Library?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SharePoint workflows are triggered by List events Create/Edit or based on a manual action so the answer would be no.  You could potentially write some kind of scheduled job that inserts a record into the SharePoint list, but the most robust method would be just build a timer job that can be scheduled to run monthly.

Here is an MSDN resource for creating customer timer jobs:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc406686(v=office.12).aspx

Comment: Thanks Mike, are there any "no-code" method?

Comment: hm.. maybe use powershell ::) It will work you just have to right some scripts.Let me know

Comment: +1 The only thing I can think of would be a console application that uses web services and runs on your desktop. You could schedule it via Windows Task Scheduler but that really is hack.

Comment: I've done the scheduled job/console app in the past.  It works, but it wasn't nearly as robust or reliable as a well written timer job.  With no access to the server, that is the way to go, but you still need coding skills.  If you have no coding skills, then this is a lot harder.

Comment: Hi najicoder, Mike and Kit - may I ask for your feedback & comments for the coding located in http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/19207/powershell-script-that-modify-itemss-value-in-sharepoint-2007-list-library-recur